# Can't understand capacitors in DC and AC

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

So if I have a capacitor of capacitance C then the current across it will be given by
$$i=C \,\frac{dV}{dt}$$
where $V$ stands for the voltage of the source in the given circuit.

My question is now, why is it that by this equation the current for the DC source coming out to be $0$ (since the derivative of a constant is zero), when of course the current will be non zero at the instant it is connected to the source $E$ ?

However, the equation works just fine for the AC source $V$ giving the result
$$i=\omega \,C\, V_o \cos \omega t$$
Which is what would be expected.

[image]

Comment: If the voltage across the capacitor is *constant*, the current through is zero.  So, if there is a DC voltage source across the capacitor *for all time*, the current through is zero.  If, instead, you connect a DC voltage source across an uncharged capacitor at some time $t = 0$, the voltage across the capacitor is clearly *not* a constant for all time.  Also, you should consider placing a very small resistance in series with the (ideal) DC source and look at the solution as this resistance goes to zero.

Comment: I actually assume that the capacitor is initially uncharged if that was not clear. Now I assume by Kirchoff's voltage law that the voltage across the capacitor at all points in time is equal to the voltage of the DC source. But this sounds odd even though this exact argument is applied to the AC circuit. Also what do you mean by 'solution as the resistance goes to zero'. Do you mean the current or the voltage?

Comment: In your first equation $V$ stands for the potential difference across the capacitor.

Comment: Real power supplies, conductors, and capacitors have resistance and parasitic inductance, so the uncharged capacitor won't instantly charge to match the DC source voltage. Once the circuit comes to equilibrium, dV and i will both be 0. With the AC source, obviously it won't come to equilibrium.

Comment: Sillysack, you've contradicted yourself.  In your post, you write "when of course the current will be non-zero *at the instant it is connected to the source* $E$" (emphasis mine).  But, in your comment back to me, you write "I assume ... that the voltage across the capacitor *at all points in time* is equal to the voltage of the DC source" (again, emphasis mine).  Do you see the conflict between these two statements?

Comment: I do, but the statement in the post is my intuition and the statement in the comment is a rule I know. Yes, they both contradict.

Comment: @Farcher Yes but since the capacitor is connected to nothing but the battery/AC source, the voltage should be equal to the source since $E-(q/C)=0$.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff So you're saying that if this was a circuit with absolute zero resistance, the current in the circuit would be zero at $t=0$? But even then shouldn't there be some current that would still flow across the capacitor? Or am I interpreting this wrong?

Comment: Sillysack, if you will do as I recommend and insert a resistance $r$ is series with the DC voltage source, you will find that the voltage across the capacitor is (assuming the capacitor is initially uncharged and connected across the DC voltage source at time $t = 0$) $$v_C(t) = E(1 - e^{-\frac{t}{rC}})$$  You can take the time derivative of this and find that the current is $$i_C(t) = \frac{E}{r}e^{-\frac{t}{rC}}$$ and see that the current is unbounded as $r$ goes to zero.  In addition, the time constant goes to zero so the current goes to an impulse.  This is unphysical though.

Answer (score 1):

In some ways your question is linked to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/399658/in-an-ac-inductive-circuit-the-applied-voltage-is-equal-to-the-back-emf/399748#399748) and a number of others.

Once you start having ideal components in a circuit and try to deduce what happens you might find conceptual difficulties.
It is better to start with a more realistic situation which in this case would be to include inductance and resistance in the circuit and then infer what happens as the resistance and inductance values are made smaller and smaller.

Both your circuit are based on the solutions of the differential equation $L\frac{dI}{dt}+RI+\frac{Q}{C}= V(t)$ but with different initial conditions.
The DC situation is equivalent to applying a step voltage to the circuit and the AC situation is the application of a sinusoidal varying voltage to the circuit.

In the DC case the current would, immediately after the switch is closed, reach a maximum and then decay away to zero when the capacitor is fully charged.
With the AC source, provided the resistance and capacitance are small, you will get the relationship $V=L\frac{dI}{dt}$ where $V$ is the voltage of the power supply because the voltages across the resistor and the capacitor are so small.

**Update** as a result of a comment from @SillysackButtowski

If you leave out the inductance then when the switch is closed the charging current goes from zero to $\frac{E}{R}$ instantaneously where $R$ is the resistance of the resulting series circuit of capacitor, cell and leads.

So assume that the equation to be solved is $RI+\frac{Q}{C}=E$ for times greater than zero.

The charge on the capacitor is given by $Q(t) = CE\left (1-\exp \left ( -\dfrac {t}{RC}\right) \right) $ and the current in the circuit is given by $I(t) = \dfrac ER \exp \left( - \dfrac{t}{RC}\right )$

The time constant of the circuit is $RC$ and if you make $R=0$ you unrealistic solutions with the capacitor charging the instant the switch is closed during which infinitesimally small period of time the current is infinite.

So better start with a finite value of resistance $R$ and see what happens as the resistance becomes smaller and smaller.

As $R$ is reduced it takes a shorter time for the capacitor to charge up but the final change on the capacitor $CE$ is independent of the value of the resistance.

Looking at the current dependence you will note that as the resistance decreases the current initial current, $\frac ER $, increases whilst the rate at which the current decreases increases.
The important thing to note is that the area under an current versus time graph is the charge which flows and that stays constant at $CE$.

I have illustrated this in the graphs below where the areas under each of the graphs is the same which in this example id one coulomb.

[image]

Comment: Could you show me your thinking process and solve the differential equation but assume that the circuit has no inductance for simplicity.

Comment: @SillysackButtowski I have added to my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Alright, I'm convinced about DC but why is having no resistance in AC causing no problems?

Comment: @SillysackButtowski For the capacitor and resistor you can do a similar analysis and show that as the resistance becomes very small compared with the reactance of the capacitor the phase angle tends to $-90 ^\circ$ and the voltage across the capacitor tends to the  voltage of the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

For a DC source, the current across the capacitor after the switch is first closed (while the capacitor is charging) should be something like

$$I(t) = I_0 exp(-t/RC),$$

where $R$ is the Ohmic resistance of the circuit, C is the capacitance of your capacitor and $I_0$ is given by $V/R$.

After a long time ($t\gg RC$), the capacitor will be completely charged, and the voltage will be equal and opposite to the DC source—only then will the current across the capacitor be zero.